# Reposition the camera in three.js

Tags: javascript, camera, three.js, perspectivecamera

I am drawing a cone on the flat surface using custom `THREE.Geometry`.
Here is the camera settings I am using:

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 1.3, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.set(90, 60, 220);
```

The camera is pointing at the mesh from the top, and it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aArSf.png)

I want the camera to provide a side view rather than top.
I am using OrbitControls to move around the scene.

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.target = new THREE.Vector3(60,75,0);
controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;
```

How do I make the camera pointing from the side (or rotate the mesh), like on [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwcLo.png) image?
I tried rotating the mesh with `mesh.rotation.x = Math.PI/2;` but then I get it upside down. What can be the correct way to rotate the it?

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: Can you edit [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akmcv7Lh/) and demonstrate your issue?

Comment: I used AxisHelper from your example, and it helped me to re-think and solve the problem! I ended up rotating the mesh, and slightly adjusted the camera. Thank you!